# Asking a non-Jew to turn off a light on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles, electricity

If I would like to turn off a light on Shabbat can I ask a non-Jew to turn off the light since it's a shvut deshvut?

(ie- electricity is a derabanan and amira lnochri is also shvut)

Comment: Shvut d’shvut is not generally permitted, absent a significant need or for mitzvah purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In **Rabbi Ribiat**'s  "[39 Melachos Book](https://mekorjudaica.com/the-39-melochos.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwzPXlBRAjEiwAj_XTEWlonVAw5ogHrxosvHvosgvCyjkA1lZpN8MhQTBWQY4wbHfIocqewRoCcDAQAvD_BwE)" (vol 1, pg 64)--cited [in this Halachapedia.com footnote](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Amirah_LeNochri#cite_note-7)-- he rules that "**one may not ask a non-Jew to shut the lights**."

As usual with these type of things, best bet would be to [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)